# how to inject script only for the first body?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I injected some script to the html page and I am trying to inject some html code to the same page by using this code

```
$.get(chrome.extension.getURL('/pages/template.html'), function(data) {
    $(data).appendTo('body');
})
```

So it works, but if there are some iframes in the page's html code, the injecting html code injects to the iframes too and that's not what I want I want to inject the html code only to the first page's body, the main body, the super body

Comment: `$(data).appendTo(window.top.document.body);`?

Comment: No it doesn't work, I tried

Comment: `$("body").filter(":first").append($(data))`?

Answer (score 0):

add some class or id to your main body

```
<body class='mainBody'>....</body>

$.get(chrome.extension.getURL('/pages/template.html'), function(data) {
      $(data).appendTo('.mainBody');
})
```

Comment: this is an extension and it can be used on every page you've opened, so class or id is not suitable

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your attention, but the solution was such a simple I have just to use the following code on manifest `all_frames:false`

Answer (score -1):

Why not `html > body`?

```
$.get(chrome.extension.getURL('/pages/template.html'), function(data)
{
    $(data).appendTo('html > body');
});
```

Comment: Iframe has html too.

Comment: DOH! I forgot. Thanks!